# How can I keep or make a new network from top 5% weighted edges?

Tags: r, networking, igraph, edges

I am trying to reduce a large network to only the top 5% of its edges, determined by edge weight.

I usually trim my networks by declaring a cut-off point for edge weight like so:

```
g2 <- delete.edges(g1, E(g1) [weight<20])
```

Is there a way to delete the lower 95% of the edges according to weight, something like:

```
g2 <- delete.edges(g1, E(g1) [weight outside the top 5%])
```

Or to extract the top 5% otherwise?

Comment: You can use `quantile()` to calculate the 5% quantile (the value that divides into 5% and 95%) and then use it as cut-off point.

Answer (score 2):

There was no example posted and only minimal code offered, and I am worried that just supplying a "weight" may hide the use of `attach`. Perhaps:

```
g2 <- delete.edges(g1, E(g1) [ weight < quantile(weight, 0.95) ])
```